# What does this sentence "10% studying engineering got PhDs."mean?

Tags: meaning

I encountered a problem asking:

> Which of the following is true about women studying in university?
>   A: 10% studying engineering got PhDs.

I am not sure what the option A means. Does it mean 10% of women studying engineering got PhDs?

Comment: By the looks of it, that's what it sounds like. In order to say something more concrete, definitely some more context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers will often omit words when there can be no doubt about what they mean.
'10%' is a determiner defining a quantity of the noun that follows it.
'studying engineering' is an adjectival phrase modifying the noun it follows.
Obviously the speaker has chosen to omit the noun. 
In this case, it would be clear from whatever came before this sentence that the omitted noun was 'women'.

Welcome to the English language! ;) I'm sorry, but you'll find many of us speak very poorly at times - simply because we know whoever is listening will understand what we mean.